# Deployed django app error: Relation does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I deployed a django app using a postresql database with Heroku.
The app works perfectly on my local machine but when I want to create a user or to login using the deployed app, I run into the following error:

```
ProgrammingError at /register/

relation "register_user" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "register_user" WHERE "register_user"...
                               ^

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    https://the-gecko.herokuapp.com/register/
Django Version:     4.0.3
Exception Type:     ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    

relation "register_user" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "register_user" WHERE "register_user"...
                               ^

Exception Location:     /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py, line 89, in _execute
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version:     3.9.10
Python Path:    

['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python39.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

Server time:    Mon, 21 Mar 2022 19:59:58 +0000
```

I believe this error has something do to with my postgres database, but I don't know what relevant code to share in that case.

Please, let me know if you have any idea how to solve that issue.

Comment: Have you run `manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Iain, I added this line ```release: python3 manage.py migrate``` to my Procfile, and now it's working. Thanks !